# How To disable "shadow-gradient" of format?

Tags: highcharts

I think it is very strange....

Suddenly, the number of the format has a shade (shadow), but I have not modified the code.

How is this possible?

Before the number was simply BLACK.

http://jsfiddle.net/0fqmoqwa/3/

```
   format: 0
```

Comment: If you're linking to the highcharts cdn for you code, they just released the latest version which will have affected the default styles for data labels, among other things. See the change log: http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/changelog

Comment: :( now i understanding :((( now is changed also the distance between axis's title and axis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `dataLabels.style` has `textShadow: "0 0 6px contrast, 0 0 3px contrast"`.

You can just overwrite this by setting `textShadow: "0"`. For example:

```
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                textShadow: "0" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0fqmoqwa/4/). The default styles are mentioned in [the API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.dataLabels.style).